# Why app name not showing on the top while installing?

Tags: android

please help I extracted my apk but app name not showing on the top of install wizard. See the image

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn't set the `android:label` name in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Make sure you have something like this:

```
<activity 
    android:label="App Name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:name=".activity.LauncherActivity">
</activity>
```